# JWT authorization header returning as undefined

Tags: javascript, express, jwt

I am trying to implement the usage of JWT but it seems that my token is not being stored.

this is the creating of the token...

```
router.post('/index', async (req, res) => {
  let post = { //retreive user input
    username: req.body.username,
    password: req.body.password,
  }

  try {
    const user = await dbb('users').first('*').where({username: post.username}); 
    if(!user) {
      res.render(path.resolve('./myviews/index'), { //display if user is not found
                info: 'The Username Or Password You Have Entered Does Not Match Our Records'
              });
    } 
    if(user) {
      const validPass = await bcrypt.compare(post.password, user.password);
      if(validPass){
      const token = jwt.sign(`${user}`, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN);

      res.json({token: token});
      res.redirect('/home');
         
        

      } else {
        res.render(path.resolve('./myviews/index'), { //display if user is not found
                info: 'The Username Or Password You Have Entered Does Not Match Our Records'
              }); 
      }
    }  
  } catch(e) {
    console.log(e);
  }

  
  
});
```

this is the function that is supposed to use the token...

```
function authToken(req, res, next) {
  const authHeader = req.headers['authorization'];

  if(typeof authHeader !== 'undefined') {
    console.log("here")
    const bearer = authHeader.split(' ');
    const bearerToken = bearer[1];
    req.token = bearerToken;
    next();
  } else {
    res.sendStatus(401);
  }
```

im wondering if anyone can help me understand where i am going wrong

Comment: You cannot use both `res.json()` and `res.redirect()`

Comment: so where am i going wrong?

Comment: Where is the client supposed to get the token from to use in future requests if you redirect away from the response with the token in it?

Comment: i thought that was what the    res.json({token: token}); did but im probably wrong. Is there a good way to do it?